How to get inaccessible object when I can't declare it as public
Probably repeat question because it's so simple, but I can't find an answer to my problem. I'm new to c# and coding in general, and am still a little confused on objects and classes.
I want to access the data in the defaultChar object from the Character class, but the data is inaccessible due to scope. I know I could just move defaultChar but I don't want a ton of character data in my Program class (I want a lot more fields then just "alias" and more characters), how do I access this without putting it in Program?
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Character character = new();
        Console.WriteLine (character.defaultChar.alias); 
        // Error 'Character.defaultChar' is inaccessible due to its protection level
    }
}

public class Character
{
    public string alias {get; set;}
    
    Character defaultChar = new()
    {
        alias = "No Encontrado",
    };
}

I tried making defaultChar public but that obviously doesn't work, I tried using a method with the data but I would end up returning a ton of data anyway. I'm not really sure what to do.
Thank you in advance for taking the time to read this.

Not only should it be public, I think it should also be static. It will then be created only once, and you can access it as Character.Default. This is a very common practice.

Please observe standard C# naming conventions- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/coding-style/identifier-names - Alias, DefaultChar


I tried making defaultChar public but that obviously doesn't work

Yes it does.  But then you encounter a different problem.  Specifically, an infinite recursion.  This is because when you create an instance of Character:
Character character = new();

That involves... creating an instance of Character:
Character defaultChar = new()
{
    alias = "No Encontrado",
};

Which then also creates an instance of Character, which then also creates an instance of Character, etc.
Every instance doesn't need this same defaultChar individual to each instance.  Instead, you probably just want one "global" defaultChar.  To do that, you can make it static so it's associated with the class itself and not with any given instance.
For example:
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Character.defaultChar.alias); 
    }
}

public class Character
{
    public string alias {get; set;}
    
    public static Character defaultChar = new()
    {
        alias = "No Encontrado",
    };
}


Oh that makes perfect sense, I kept thinking I needed to declare defaultChar inside of Program rather than just being able to access it outright, thank you for your help
